# Tooltip clipped when overflow is set to auto

Tags: html, css

My layout has a sidebar on the left, and a content section on the right. Both sides have their own scroll bar and should take up the remaining height of the page.

My problem is that when I set `overflow-y: auto` so that I can have the scrollbar, the tooltip (from Bootstrap 3) gets clipped if it leaves the containing `div`.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Ljy1nc3v/3/

Setting `z-index` on the `content` class and even the `tooltip` class doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Kudos for the question title. Perfect description of my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is to set a container attribute on your tooltip like this:

```
$(".tt").tooltip({
    placement: "top",
    title: "<h3>this is a test tooltip</h3>",
    html: true,
    container: 'body'
});
```

This will append your tooltip to the `body` element rather than `.content div`.

Answer (score 0):

check out this just remove the `position:absolute` for the `.content`

css

```
h1 { margin: 0; }

.header {
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: #00e9ff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 20%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
    background-color: #ffd800;
    margin-left: 20%;
    width: 80%;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for taking the time to answer. Indeed, removing the absolute position will stop the clipping. But that introduces a problem with the scrolling... I can't seem to get both of them working at the same time.

Comment: can u change the placement from to right
`$(".tt").tooltip({
    placement: "right",
    title: "<h3>this is a test tooltip</h3>",
    html: true
});`

Answer (score 0):

Because the sidebar and content divs are not positioned properly the tooltip is not displaying correctly. The problem is that both content and sidebar divs are rendered from the start of y-axis and sidebar dive is overflown on the content div. So when the tooltip is rendered, some part of the tooltip is getting rendered behind sidebar div.

To avoid this, both divs should be rendered side-by-side. For that you need to create additional two div containers for sidebar and content divs. On the top container div use `display:table;` property, On the inside container div use `display: table-row;` property and on the sidebar and content divs use `display:table-cell;` property.
This will place sidebar and content divs side-by-side and now you can see complete tootip.

Code :

```js
$(".tt").tooltip({
  placement: "top",
  title: "<h3>this is a test tooltip</h3>",
  html: true
});
```

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
.top-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.innter-container {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}
.sidebar {
  background-color: #00e9ff;
  display: table-cell;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.content {
  background-color: #ffd800;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <h1>Header stuff</h1>
</div>

<div class="top-container">
  <div class="innter-container">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="sidebar">
      stuff1
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff2
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff3
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff4
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff5
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff6
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff7
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <a href="#" class="tt">tooltip stuff</a>
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff2
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>
      <a href="#" class="tt">tooltip stuff2</a>
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff4
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff5
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff6
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff7
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>stuff
      <br/>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using the Bootstrap 3 data-toggle and @theseeker your solution worked for me by adding container: 'body' to:

```
        $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]', container: 'body' });
```

Thanks for the info!